# XML Serialization put alias on a field without using [XmlElement("aliasName")]

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

I want to serialize a class with two object fields

```
   public object Status{get:...set:...}
   public object Data{get:...set:...}
```

I want to rename the "Data" field in the output XML file. But i must be able to change the name with some setAlias("Data", "RenamedField") like function. (not with a static  [XmlElement("aliasName")] tag in the sourcefile)

I've done it with JsonExSerializer but don't know how to do it with System.Xml.Serialization.

Thanks for your advices,
- Jeremy.

Comment: Why is the attribute insufficient?

Comment: I use the same class to contains different types. This class is then serialized as a restful web service answer. I want the data node to be named with the contained type: <status>...</status><line></line> or <status>...</status><circle></circle> it was working with Json serializer but now i need to implement XML output

Comment: This is most likely a flaw in your applications architecture.

Comment: I think so, was hoping for some kind of dirty workaround ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface and create the XML yourself.

Comment: I'm going to implement IXmlSerializable and do the trick in the WriteXml method. Thank you!